# How to compare two UIButtons for equality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have two instances of a UIButton, both obtained from the storyboard: one through `IBOutlet UIButton myStar` and one as the parameter `sender` of `-(IBAction) buttonClicked:(UIButton *) sender`. How do I compare `myStar` and `sender` without getting false negatives? Although I dragged and dropped from the storyboard, I believe they are two different instances with two different `id`s.

I can't simply compare the titles or image names because I have multiple such buttons with the same titles and image names.

Comment: If they are the same button a simple pointer comparison with `==` should be fine.

Comment: At a high level, basically all the "dragging and dropping" does is point the instance variable to that instantiated by the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find that `sender == myStar` is true, because they are pointers to the same button, because it sounds like you ctrl+dragged to create an IBOutlet UIButton, then you dragged and dropped to create a IBAction buttonClicked (which passes sender).

`sender == myStar` always, unless you are calling `buttonClicked` and passing it other variables programmatically , or if another button from interface builder is linked to that IBAction.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare two UIButtons by using their tag property, before comparing set tag property for each UIButton. Remember that tag property must be unique.

```
if (myStar.tag == sender.tag)
{
     code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sender == myStar` indicates that `sender` is the same instance of `myStar`, not another instance of `UIButton` with (maybe accidentally) same value.

In the context, `sender == myStar` literally means "`sender` of the message is `myStar`".

From your description, I believe that you want to make sure the two pointers point to the same object. In this case `sender == myStar` is the correct way to do it.